# Managed Beans JSF

Tags: jsf

I am making a web application using JSF consisting in a task manager. In this application there are two kind of users, the administrator and the normal users. I have a User class and to know whether a user is an administrator or not I have an attribute (boolean isAdmin;). At the beginng the user has to specify the username and the password of the account and depending on the rol (administrator or normal user) he will be redirected to the administrator page or the normal user page.

Now I only have one managed bean that is in charge of the login and all the different actions of the two kind of users. My teacher told me that it will be necessary to have the bean in charge of the loggin with a session scope in orther to know if the user is logged or not and avoid free navigation (for example avoid that a normal user eneters in the page of the administrator). So would it be better to have two separated beans one for the administrator and other for the normal user and inject them in the login bean, or the approach that I am using now (with only one bean) is better?

Comment: no need of two separate mangedBean you will need to fixe some roles for your user and your administrator and every time work with rendred pages, would you like an example to understand how it's working

Comment: @YagamiLight In the application the normal user will have a list of task, and the administrator a list of users (the users of the application and he will be able to delete or disable them). Now this two list are in the login bean and reading your answer I understand that this is the better aproach isn't it?

Comment: the administrator is a kind of a super user he will have more priviléges that the user you hold the opivilege in the same table, this mean every user (even administraor) have a list of privileges and every time the user connect you get it from the database